# Menu Display Block Not Positioning Correctly

Tags: css, css-float, displaytag, css-position

Help!  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this menu??  I can't get it to be in line with the other menu (scoot up) and the drop down doesn't stay and is behind everything.  Help please :) is my site.  Thanks!!

[This is my Website](http://joshuatrent.com)

(Also I know it's not good to use absolute positioning, is there anyone that can tell me how to make that menu be where it is without absolute?)

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem with my website. wat worked for me was that i changed the control's related css's display property to inherit, which was previously inline.

```
#menu li
{
//      display:inline;
    display:inherit;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #FF3737;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did work to fix the drop down problem but it also extended the bars to the right edge of the page :-/ it didn't fix the problem with being below the other menu.  Thank you thank you for your help though!